# Access remote database from Jenkins Pipeline when jenkins does not have DB

Tags: mysql, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cloud-foundry

I have to access the cloud foundry Database from Jenkins. So for that, I have forwarded the Cloud Foundry SQL port to Jenkins local port.

On Jenkins, I have installed database and SQl plugin and trying to connect on localhost:3306 port. But, it is giving below error:

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

- cf ssh app-name -L 3306:192.168.32.29:3306
  [Pipeline] sh
- mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u user-name -ppassword db-name
  ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Comment: I think instead of using localhost, you need to use the ip address of the host where mysql server is running.

Comment: it is because of cloud foundry, that we don't know about host ip of SQL server, we can only forward port for accessing SQL.

Comment: Can you check which port MySQL is running on cloud foundry, is it something other than 3306 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was happening because cf ssh app-name -L 3306:192.168.32.29:3306 was getting executed and then terminating the ssh before next command is run.

So in my case, mysql was not able to find any database linked to that port.

To solve this issue, I had to run the the first ssh command in background and the run the next mysql command.

cf ssh ${appName} -N -L 3306:${db_ip}:3306 &
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u user-name -ppassword db-name < 'mysqlstatements.sql'

Once the operation is done, we can close the background command using kill command